# How to increase site performance by CSS and JS blocks from external Extensions

Tags: performance, seo, optimization

Hi here my site getting **E** grade rating in GTmetrix because of some CSS and JS files which came with some extensions.

message as Critical am getting:

`Resources are blocking the first paint of your page. Consider delivering critical JS/CSS inline and deferring all non-critical JS/styles. Resources that may be contributing to render-blocking include:`

location:

`https://cdn-static.mysite.com/pub/static/_po_compressor/7eee56dfac4ded36b3f1bc94233459d4.css`

**Avoid Changing Critical Requests**

`The Critical Request Chains below show you what resources are loaded with a high priority. Consider reducing the length of chains, reducing the download size of resources, or deferring the download of unnecessary resources to improve page load.`

is there a way to optimize these kind of issues.
can I get some help? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some pointers :

1. Disable modules not in use : this will reduce JS pay load.
2. Do not merge JS.
3. Call minimum JS above Fold ( differ, async and calling JS as late as possible is the way out )
4. Use requireJs effectively
5. Try JS advance bundle

Objective should be to reduce JS payload on a given page to be less then 500 KB.
Also to make sure that there is minimum JS dependency above fold.

There are considerable efforts to do this but its worth spending time and moving out JS using different tricks ( disbale modules, make sure unwanted modules are not call on a given page if not in use, remove blocks, disable plugins if not in use )

Comment: thank you @Oscprofessionals for response.

Comment: welcome..There are incremental steps that should be taken for optimization.

Comment: Also check DB tables for not cleaned tables and do clean those.